# ¿Clausula CASE en PIVOT? SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2008-r2

Buenas gente,

Tengo esta consulta con un pivot que me arroja estos datos:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @space NVARCHAR (10),
    @x NVARCHAR (10) 

    set @date1 = '''01/06/2013'''
    set @date2 = '''30/06/2013'''
    set @space = ''''''
    set @x = '''X'''

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DAY(a.FECHA))
                    from dbo.CALENDARIO AS a
                    WHERE a.FECHA between @date1 AND @date2 
                    group by a.FECHA
                    order by a.FECHA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT pvt.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
       left(datename(day,DATEFIELD),3)as [day],
        FIELD1 AS FIELD1
    FROM dbo.TABLEFROMDDBB
    WHERE FIELD2 = 0 
    AND FIELD1 = 0
    AND DATEFIELD between ' + @date1 + ' AND ' + @date2 + ' 
    AND FIELD3 = 'xxx'
    AND FIELD4 = 123456789
    AND FIELD5 = 'xxxx'
) as s
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(FIELD1)
    FOR [day] IN (' + @cols + ')
)AS pvt' 

execute(@query);
```

### [image: Resultado Consulta]

Lo que necesita el cliente es que en vez de 1 y 0 se vea una X cuando es un 1 y null cuando es 0, se que esto se debe de aplicar con un case como este:

```
CASE WHEN FIELD1 IS not null THEN 'X'  ELSE ''  END AS FIELD1
```

he probado varias formulas pero todas me devuelven el error de que no se reconoce el campo FIELD1

Lo he introducido en esta parte de la consulta:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' AS [day], CASE WHEN FIELD1 IS NOT null THEN 'X'  ELSE ''  END AS FIELD1
```

pero, como os digo, me da el error de que no conoce los campos.

Se agradecen todo tipo de soluciones.

Gracias de antebrazo :)

Comment: pero en que parte estas ejecutando ese query? eso no esta del todo claro.

Comment: si hombre en la última línea pone claramente 

execute(@query);

Y me da los datos de la tabla que he puesto

Comment: esta linea? SET query = 'SELECT ' + cols + ' AS [day], CASE WHEN FIELD1 IS NOT null THEN 'X'  ELSE ''  END AS FIELD1 no tiene ni from, a eso me refiero. entiendo que venga de ahi, pero sin contexto dificil saber que te pasa...

Comment: me lo estás diciendo en serio tron? Si te fijas bien he cambiado esta parte de la consulta por la siguiente que pongo
`"SET query = 'SELECT pvt.*"

"SET query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' AS [day], CASE WHEN FIELD1 IS NOT null THEN 'X'  ELSE ''  END AS FIELD1"`

lo que pasa que no controlo tanto de sql y no se si realmente es en esa parte donde tengo que incluir mi case o es en otra parte de la 2ª consulta...

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tratar de crear esa expresión `CASE` dinámicamente también. Algo similar a:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @date2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @space NVARCHAR (10),
    @x NVARCHAR (10) 

    set @date1 = '''01/06/2013'''
    set @date2 = '''30/06/2013'''
    set @space = ''''''
    set @x = '''X'''

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DAY(a.FECHA))
                    from dbo.CALENDARIO AS a
                    WHERE a.FECHA between @date1 AND @date2 
                    group by a.FECHA
                    order by a.FECHA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')


select @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT ',CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(DAY(a.FECHA)) + ' IS NOT NULL THEN ''X'' ELSE '' END AS' + QUOTENAME(DAY(a.FECHA)) 
                    from dbo.CALENDARIO AS a
                    WHERE a.FECHA between @date1 AND @date2 
                    group by a.FECHA
                    order by a.FECHA
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols2 + '
FROM (
    SELECT 
       left(datename(day,DATEFIELD),3)as [day],
        FIELD1 AS FIELD1
    FROM dbo.TABLEFROMDDBB
    WHERE FIELD2 = 0 
    AND FIELD1 = 0
    AND DATEFIELD between ' + @date1 + ' AND ' + @date2 + ' 
    AND FIELD3 = 'xxx'
    AND FIELD4 = 123456789
    AND FIELD5 = 'xxxx'
) as s
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(FIELD1)
    FOR [day] IN (' + @cols + ')
)AS pvt' 

execute(@query);
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo y te cuento, muchas gracias

Comment: Nada macho me da el mismo error

"El nombre de columna 'FIELD1' no es válido."

:(

Comment: @TonyWaters Extraño, porque lo de `FIELD1` es de la consulta que pusiste y que dijiste que entrega resultados

Comment: Si que es extraño, estuve anoche con un colega mirando y debería de funcionar pero no lo hace, no obstante voy a seguir tirando por este camino porque es el camino bueno, te lo agradezco muchísimo y en cuanto encuentre la forma correcta lo pondré por aquí para que quede la cuestión resuelta de una vez por toda, muchas fracias de nuevo, compañero